# winsock and new thread does not release memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock2

I have a really strange problem. Looking for the cause on the web and try everything. Nothing helps.

First case:

(This works exactly as expected. Windows task manager shows the constant memory size, and does not increase.)

```
unsigned long WINAPI thfun(void * arg)
{
    ::Sleep(50);
    ::ExitThread(0);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const wchar_t ** argv)
{
    HANDLE th = 0;
    DWORD thid, err;
    while (true)
    {
        th = ::CreateThread(0, 0, thfun, 0, 0, &thid);
        if (!th)
        {
            err = ::GetLastError();
        }
        ::WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Second case:

```
unsigned long WINAPI thfun(void * arg)
{
    ::Sleep(50);
    ::ExitThread(0);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const wchar_t ** argv)
{
    WORD ver;
    WSADATA wsadata;
    ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    if (WSAStartup(ver, &wsadata)) return 1;

    ::Sleep(50);

    HANDLE th = 0;
    DWORD thid, err;
    while (true)
    {
        th = ::CreateThread(0, 0, thfun, 0, 0, &thid);
        if (!th)
        {
            err = ::GetLastError();
        }
        ::WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I call any function from winsock least once created threads do not release memory.
Windows task manager shows ever-growing memory of my application.

What should I do so that I achieve the same behavior as in the first case when I use winsock?

I use visual studio 2013

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Maybe not related, but you should probably invoke `CloseHandle` on the thread when done with it?

Comment: What he/she said^.. BUT Why call `ExitThread`.  From the docs: **ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.** You're not leaking anything but this is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @lukino I got the feeling that there is some code missing in your sample. You do not call any socket function. I think the error lies in the lines you deleted for the sample.

Answer (score 1):

You do not close your thread handles. A common error.

Your core loop should look like that:

```
while (true)
{
    th = ::CreateThread(0, 0, thfun, 0, 0, &thid);
    if (!th)
    {
        err = ::GetLastError();
    }
    ::WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(th);
}
```

That problem exists in both of your examples. That memory grow of the second sample can be a side effect.

`ExitThread(0)` is never a good idea and I do not understand why Microsoft recommand it for C. As the Winsock API should not have any destructor, it should not be a problem. Nevertheless, do not use it.

**UPDATE**

I tested your code as release on a Windows 7 64bit SP1 System with Antivira personal installed (my gaming machine). Also on my Windows 8 VM (parallels). Both system did not show the problems you described and show in your video. This is IMHO good news for you, because it seems a problem of your installation and not a general problem.
The video shows a leak of only a few bytes per ended thread and strict linear growing per thread. This looks for me like thread associated information, usually stored nowadays in TLS (**T**hread **L**ocal **S**torage). Also it only appears when you init The WSASocket system. If the WSASocket system itself would be the problem, we would found reports of it for sure(but I didn't). I believe a hook DLL is causing that problem, a DLL is informed over the DllMain of any started or ended thread of the process. Any virus scanner or keyboard addon(!) can cause such a problem as they usually use hook DLLs and manipulate IOs like pipes and sockets.

Unfortunatly I only know one way to find out:

1. Make a release canditate of your sample. Make sure the problem exist.
2. Make a clean install of Windows 7
3. Install step by step the environment you use on your produktive system. Make sure you restart the Computer after every step.
4. Hopefully find the culprit.

Deactivating or uninstall hooks may help but need not. Unfortunately installing programs on windows system is maximal inversive.

Sorry for not heaving the easy answer.

Comment: Not at all.

Although I am using the :: CloseHandle (th) memory still growing. Although I will not use ExitThread still growing memory. All this, of course, I really tried. If anyone has time, it can try. ;) I've tried about every combination.

Comment: @lukino I run your samples on Win 8 with VS2013. No leaks :-( Have you some more code?

Comment: Your answer is not really good. I had to do a video. It best described my problem. http://youtu.be/t7tVJ-PGOPo

Comment: @lukino Awesome video :-) ...and I have to admit, the evidence speaking for you :-D. It is not much memory which is leaking, so I guess it is TLS (Thread Local storage) used bei winsocks. I will try to reproduce your problem, unfortunatly not today, but tomorrow. I use a VM for such kind of test. You are using Windows 8? Is it up to date? (I need this information for setting up the VM). And you should update your question.

Comment: It is a lot of memory. This was an example. In the real application a new thread is always created when sending data for a continuous operation of the program the amount of the lost memory causes a big trouble. I use win7 x64 sp1.

Comment: @lukino You misunderstood, I did not implied that small leak size is a small problem :-) the like size was more a hint for me. I found some time so I did some updates to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I try another install new windows or as a VM. I'll write if it succeeds. ;)